# How to fetch a List-type from Pytorch DataLoader?

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I'm trying to got List-type data while itering the DataLoader. Here is a simple example:

```
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader,Dataset

tests = [('test resume1',[1,2,3]),
         ('test resume2',['a','b','c']),
         ('test resume3',['Q',"W",'E']),
         ('test resume4',[',','.','/']),
         ('test resume5',['!','@','#'])]

class testdataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.x = [item[0] for item in data]
        self.y = [item[1] for item in data]
    def __getitem__(self,index):
        return self.x[index],self.y[index]
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.x)
    
temp = testdataset(tests)
print(temp[0])
pack = DataLoader(temp,batch_size=2,shuffle=True)
for i,unit in enumerate(pack):
    print(i,type(unit),len(unit))
    print(unit)
```

I'm looking forward to print every batch like **[('test resume2', 'test resume4'), [('a', 'b', 'c' ), (',', '.', '/')]]**, while the result is:

```
('test resume1', [1, 2, 3])
0 <class 'list'> 2
[('test resume2', 'test resume4'), [('a', ','), ('b', '.'), ('c', '/')]]
1 <class 'list'> 2
[('test resume5', 'test resume1'), [('!', 1), ('@', 2), ('#', 3)]]
2 <class 'list'> 2
[('test resume3',), [('Q',), ('W',), ('E',)]]
```

Why does the list being splited in the batch? How can I get the return value in Dataset?

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own `collate_fn` for the data loader to do what you want:

```py
def collate_fn(list_items):
     x = []
     y = []
     for x_, y_ in list_items:
         print(f'x_={x_}, y_={y_}')
         x.append(x_)
         y.append(y_)
     return x, y
```

Using this custom collate function:

```py
pack = DataLoader(temp,batch_size=2,shuffle=True,collate_fn=collate_fn)
for i,unit in enumerate(pack):
    print(i,type(unit),len(unit))
    print(unit)
```

will give you:

```
0 <class 'tuple'> 2
(['test resume4', 'test resume3'], [[',', '.', '/'], ['Q', 'W', 'E']])
1 <class 'tuple'> 2
(['test resume5', 'test resume1'], [['!', '@', '#'], [1, 2, 3]])
2 <class 'tuple'> 2
(['test resume2'], [['a', 'b', 'c']])
```

Please see [`torch.utils.data.DataLoader`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader) for more information on customizing the `Dataloader`.